# Can a PWA or Web App share itself to another mobile phone in an offline environment (no internet connection)?

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps, hybrid-mobile-app, offlineapps

Can a PWA or WebApp on one mobile phone be shared to another mobile phone other than via a URL?

For example, can a PWA be transferred via Bluetooth, Nearby Me, AirDrop, NFC, WhatsApp attachment, Email attachment,  SD card, etc?

Comment: For installation, the user needs to be viewing your HTTPS site and they need to explicitly agree to the install from the browser pop-up.

Comment: Like Mathias said the PWA does require being loaded via HTTPS. I don't think the service worker can be registered using the file:// protocol. But you could transfer web pages and assets via BlueTooth, except to iOS. Apple is always 2-4 years behind the world on many things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a set of [web standards](https://github.com/WICG/webpackage) being developed that will enable this. Read [Get started with Web Bundles](https://web.dev/web-bundles/) for a look at how this might work in the future.

Comment: Wow, I was unable to find this. Thank you! I'm looking forward to when this is ready!

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Android devices, yes it's possible - but not easy.

When you install a PWA on Android, it creates an APK under the covers to let you see it in the app drawer.

The catch is that the APK is auto-generated, so there's no way to tell which APK corresponds to which PWA. However, you can just grab them all if you have the Android debug tool adb and [apktool](https://apktool.org/).

```
adb shell "pm list packages --user 0 | grep org.chromium.webapk."
```

You'll get a list that looks like this:

```
package:org.chromium.webapk.a79c27b6ef85c23e5_v2
package:org.chromium.webapk.ac118272f3b0621ee_v2
....
```

So... find the paths to all of them:

```
adb "pm path org.chromium.webapk.a79c27b6ef85c23e5_v2"
adb "pm path org.chromium.webapk.ac118272f3b0621ee_v2"
...
```

This gives you paths to the APKs:

```
package:/data/app/~~ORVW-0fh4YPCMiWvVym9rw==/org.chromium.webapk.a78c276aec85c43f6_v2-AXPM5z2ED5bG0oGszEFW1g==/base.apk
package:/data/app/~~ex3iSpy2GiO_586ze1OKdA==/org.chromium.webapk.ac118272f3b0621ee_v2-XYCqDyzZ3HRjQLFrA3xmBXQ==/base.apk
...
```

Next, download the APKs. You'll need to give them local names; I used just the first 4 characters of the webapk auto-generated ID:

```
adb pull /data/app/~~ORVW-0fh4YPCMiWvVym9rw==/org.chromium.webapk.a78c276aec85c43f6_v2-AXPM5z2ED5bG0oGszEFW1g==/base.apk a78c.apk
adb pull /data/app/~~ex3iSpy2GiO_586ze1OKdA==/org.chromium.webapk.ac118272f3b0621ee_v2-XYCqDyzZ3HRjQLFrA3xmBXQ==/base.apk ac11.apk
...
```

Now that you have the APKs, extract them using apktool:

```
java -jar apktool_2.8.0.jar d a78c.apk
java -jar apktool_2.8.0.jar d ac11.apk
...
```

Each extracted APK will have a subdirectory with the APK name. In each subdirectory will be a file called AndroidManifest.xml.

Look at each AndroidManifest.xml for android:host="*some website*". That's the website that corresponds to the PWA. You can then install that on another device:

```
adb install a78c.apk
```

Voila, your PWA is now on another Android device.